# How can I add a textbox to a datagrid cell dynamically and how can I retrieve entered data? using Custom Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate, datagridcell

I have developed an invoice application and I have added a datagrid control to my WPF application. Now I need to add a textbox into a datagrid cell programatically.

Can you give me some idea about how to find textbox inside CellEditingTemplate? Please refer this screenshot - thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbInU.png)

**UserControltest.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="InvoiceApp.UserControltest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="ItemHolder" Height="30">            
    </Grid>        
</UserControl>

**Mainwindow(FrmBill.xmal):**

    <Window x:Class="InvoiceApp.FrmBill"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Testgrid" Height="300" Width="400" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Grid>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel x:Name="MydataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="350"/>
            <!--Now here i am setting the height to 0,the reason will be explained afterwards-->

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**FrmBill.cs(C# code):**

```
 string str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectInvoice"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con;
    public FrmBill()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Tax", con);     
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
UserControltest row = new UserControltest();
int trd = row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
if(row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinitions.Count==0)  
 {
     row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());//this will ad required number of columns which will represent the cells
 }    
TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
txtbx.Height = 20;  
row.ItemHolder.Children.Add(txtbx);
Grid.SetColumn(txtbx,3); /// here 1 is the column count, change it as you want :)
MydataGrid.Children.Add(row);
MydataGrid.Height = MydataGrid.Height + 30;
```

}

}

Comment: Do u really wanna do it a datagrid ? i mean u can go with a custom usercontrol if u want :)

Comment: Yes, as it says @zackraiyan it will be easier with a personalized control, although with that I do not say that what you want is not possible

Comment: Please how to do it custom user control

Comment: @Anbu , if you want a custom user control ,edit your question and mention it there,then i will post an answer :)

Comment: @zackraiyan thank you for your response i have edited the question please share this answer

Comment: yes, i am writing the answer @Anbu

Comment: @Anbu , is the data coming from a database ?

Comment: yes @zackraiyan

Comment: @Anbu , i am almost done with the answer,please wait :)

Comment: I want to entering the first cell (textbox) it will getting for data from database in second cell(textbox), third cell, like enter item code showing item name for  textbox

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentioned, he want's to go with a custom `User-control` , here's a XAML for a sample `User-Control` that may represent a `Data-Row`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyDatarow"
 ......>
  <Grid x:Name="ItemHolder" Height="30" x:FieldModifier ="Public">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />  <!--Create as many column as you want during design time,or you can simply create it dynamically -->
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" /><!--Now here i am setting the Width to 20*,instead of this you can set a MinWidth and MaxWidth if you want , i recommend it too-->
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />

  <!--When i write the c# code,i will consider that no column were added here during design time-->
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now,let's present it as a `DataGrid`.Let's assume the data is coming from a database,then we can use a `IDataReader` and also a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to achieve the `datagrid` look:

```
   <VirtualizingStackPanel x:Name="MydataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="0"/> <!--Now here i am setting the height to 0,the reason will be explained afterwards-->
```

**C#**

```
  SqlConection con=new SqlConnection("connection string here")
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table",con)
  SqlDatareader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  While (dr.Read())
   {
    MyDatarow row = new MyDatarow;
    If (row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinition.Count = 0)
     {
       row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinition.Add(new ColumnDefinition)//this will ad required number of columns which will represent the cells
     }     
    TextBox txtbx = new TextBox;
    txtbx.Height = 20
    row.ItemHolder.Children.Add(txtbx)
    Grid.SetColumn(txtbx,1) /// here 1 is the column count, change it as you want :)
    MyDatagrid.Childer.Add(row);
    MyDatagrid.height = MyDatagrid.height + 30 ;
   }
```

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: thanks @zack give some time i will implement to this coding and share with you result

Comment: @Anbu , okay :)

Comment: How can I add a user control into a wpf window like xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InvoiceApp" i am not able to import to the usercontrol can i add to any reference.?

Comment: Create the usercontrol in the same project,build it, then u will see it in the tool box , but here u don't need to add the usercontrol to the window during designtime as we're adding it dynamically

Comment: Apologise  for late response i have did this coding whatever your posted i am getting output empty please find the code i have edited the question what i made the mistake for this code

Comment: @Anbu , gimme a second please

Comment: @Anbu okay , the problem is you are adding one column to the grid but you are adding the textbox to the 3rd column which is not even created .. just repeat this line 3 times `row.ItemHolder.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());`

Comment: LOLZ!! You are not displaying the data anywhere!! Just add this `txtbx.Text = dr[0]/ToString` @Anbu

Comment: @Anbu , if you still face problems, please [join the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169897/new-roomz)